# Undefined reference error when calling a subroutine from a program

Tags: fortran

I have a main program but I want to use it as a subroutine. Therefore, I defined a subroutine inside it

```
Program main
contains     
subroutine ram_cpl    
.    
.    
.
end subroutine ram_cpl 
end program main
```

I am supposed to link it to an executable `exe1` and then use further for some external programs. I get `exe1` normally but when I call this subroutine in an external program located in a different directory, I get an error

> undefined reference to `ram_cpl'

I think the problem is occurring with the linkage as either I should declare this subroutine as public or the linkage should be done properly.

But I can use the `PUBLIC` statement only inside a module, I also checked my command line used for linkage but I did not get any clue.

```
/usr/local/bin/mpif90 -frepack-arrays -O3 -ftree-vectorize -ftree-loop-linear -funroll-loops -w -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-none -frecord-marker=4 -fconvert=big-endian -I.. master.o -o exe2 -L.. ../main.o
```

where `main.o` is the compiled program containing the subroutine and master is the another program that calls it. `exe2` is the executable I am trying to get.

This command line runs properly with other programs and I also tried to replace the `program main` with `module main` but it gave me another error.

Answer (score 3):

Your subroutine is **internal** to the program where it is declared. You cannot call it from anywhere else.

If you want to call a subroutine from multiple locations, place it in a module, do not make it internal. All subroutines in modern Fortran should be placed in a module unless you have a good reason to place them elsewhere. 
You must `use` the module when before you call the subroutine from it.

You can also make it external (after `end program`), but the module is a better and the modern way to go. External subroutine is like any other, it is just outside of any other program unit. An `external` statement should be used in the calling code (often not necessary).

Also, you cannot compile two programs at the same time. Only one main program is allowed.

Comment: I tried to convert the program into module but I got another 'undefined reference to' error that was associated with libgfortranbegin.a.

Comment: That is a completely different problem. You can ask a new question. Show your code and the complete error message.

Comment: Please remove the edit, ask a new question and show the **full** code there. See [mcve]. The code must also include the **calling** code.

Comment: Could you please elaborate further about how to declare the subroutine external after the main program. I tried by writing  **external ram_cpl** after the end program statement, but it is giving an error.

Comment: I solved this problem by changing the program into module. I created another main program which calls this subroutine.